# How the arrange the xml response in some particular design (div's & tables)

Tags: php, xml, soap

Recently i have started Flight portal website. In that for displaying the details of flight like availability, cancellation , fare , etc.. i am sending a SOAP XML request in php the code is as below

```
<?php
$xml_data="<arzHotelAvailReq><clientInfo>
<username>UdooInXML</username>
<userType>ArzooHWS1.1</userType>
<userID>77743543</userID>
<password>*CB8</password>
<partnerID>1002</partnerID>
</clientInfo>
<requestSegment>
<currency>INR</currency>
<searchType>search</searchType>
<residentOfIndia>true</residentOfIndia>
<stayDateRange>
<start>22/03/2013</start>
<end>23/03/2013</end>
</stayDateRange>
<roomStayCandidate>
<guestDetails>
<adults>1</adults>
<child>
<age>3</age>
<age>5</age>
</child>
</guestDetails>
<guestDetails>
<adults>2</adults>
<child>
<age>2</age>
</child>
</guestDetails>
</roomStayCandidate>
<hotelSearchCriteria>
<hotelCityName>BANGALORE</hotelCityName>
<hotelName></hotelName>
<area></area>
<attraction></attraction>
<rating></rating>
<sortingPreference>1
</sortingPreference>
<hotelPackage>Y</hotelPackage></hotelSearchCriteria></requestSegment></arzHotelAvailReq>
";
```

Here the soap client request code comes.

and i am getting the response. Everything is fine upto here. But i am getting the response in a irregular text format like as below.

```
100200


    INR
    search

      22/03/2013
      23/03/2013



        1

          3
          5



        2

          2




      BANGALORE




      1

      Y

    true




        00005380
        Veekay Tourist Home
        Overlooking the beautiful park, this homely abode is close to the ISKON Temple. Across three floors are 80 AC and non-AC rooms, which are maintained with room service. Guests can experience the essence of the city with a tour, which is organized by the home on demand. There is free parking facility provided to the guests to park their vehicles.

        1
        2
        400
        033
        arzooB


91/1, Railway Parallel Road Yeshwantpur

          NA

          Overlooking the beautiful park, this homely abode is close to the ISKON Temple. Across three floors are 80 AC and non-AC rooms, which are maintained with room service. Guests can experience the essence of the city with a tour, which is organized by the home on demand. There is free parking facility provided to the guests to park their vehicles.
          NA
          NA
          NA
          NA


          00:00
          12:00


          All
          NA
          NA

        Air_Conditioning,Restaurant,Conference_Hall,Health_Club,Travel_Desk,Transfers,Forex,Shopping,Swimming,Banquet,Business_Center


            NA
            cdn.travelpartnerweb.com/DesiyaImages/Image/1/nxd/maw/ryj/lbn/HO_TN.jpg





          N
          N
          Non AC Room
          No Amenities
          0000019527
          0000068265

            11111111
            +yWrLQerwfpRqCOBdo4d4Q+fTZgh1nupLJ4p4u6ke0DnoKrM1YnV+CyeKeLupHtAek/xho0eiejEOsNqkniCrj61Dp4lgPVpxhyWcxAZvAY6eaST9cxEwO77vKeHzGt7xDrDapJ4gq4OONbvuHIwesuQNW1tG3pMLXm9B6RXzcuVQyNiR9Nkmc5UwHnlMe/3R4pOa9nZpzWvpc4Pgi4QldI0kqzTn0R2SrrkswfU4tEe+FrLnNX0ikMr6KYsRwZ5weOUbgjswoE6Gc2xDYzFhoJPdnFEgTGV53WGRs0ArO3XjoptM/3++Ebal1NQKw41+CLkev7bTS2uy9dZCeYpxW/ouG38h9xmYh+h8WdKEfuf5HK8TIYqr3cMt7sdhfmbFluz6IhIkl5gGOFLUgob5fJgMkJc5m29X6/0s/8xt7Kj8slKZijCITtF+SlZboPr
            84
            751
            0
            0.0
            0



          N
          N
          AC Double
          No Amenities
          0000019528
          0000068266

            11111111
            MqJjfxbuxrY6eaST9cxEwDETzbfNeAOGmk9s1Uz6PbYSZIViwgQiY5pPbNVM+j22FHM8WEydgwBkOaDlTL6ZjC9zLGtHv0ypOnmkk/XMRMAPn02YIdZ7qUC2Sm/k4OAAweOUbgjswoF0RTNIMdh6k+Ld9K5fVWUdDznXXQXDz4XzARG+d1YhoTBLNxtfNxqmAcSIgU/v1x3EOsNqkniCrr6b1Ug4ytFJZ/0FayiZJBkPeiwpn9EJwEbIPnPEbTR4lWhM0grn0WLZ56unmN2SYl3cbsmEPmwq2OuHVC1F8Hu84Nfh1MF/h4/ba1HimMaE+uDhm6Ks2qonJVGPUcpVXdQrEjcaz9CVv8aChDAx1MrEOsNqkniCrtPU6ffG6Zo+VJRf6bY5MD9Jpvu9wmltGrCdLm1c957TFF2epIoxL54OaXRTmdyfd1yCAU1C72cA
            0
            1684
            60
            0.0
            0






        00005020
        U.G.DELUXE
        Located near to the Srinivasa Nursing Home, this brand new smoke-free property on the block is maintained with 42 deluxe rooms, which includes A/C and non-A/C accommodations. There are three dining outlets, namely Malabar Vegetarian Restaurant, Krishna Bhavan, and Sukh Sagar, which are all open for service from 6a.m to 10p.m. The property is designed with a garden area, where guests can lounge. They can also avail the assistance of the travel desk and take a tour of the beautiful city.

        0
        2
        550
        061
        arzooB


#9/1, 2nd Cross,Thulasithotam Balepet Near Srinivasa Nursing Home

          NA

          Located near to the Srinivasa Nursing Home, this brand new smoke-free property on the block is maintained with 42 deluxe rooms, which includes A/C and non-A/C accommodations. There are three dining outlets, namely Malabar Vegetarian Restaurant, Krishna Bhavan, and Sukh Sagar, which are all open for service from 6a.m to 10p.m. The property is designed with a garden area, where guests can lounge. They can also avail the assistance of the travel desk and take a tour of the beautiful city.
          NA
          NA
          NA
          NA


          00:00
          12:00


          All
          NA
          NA

        Air_Conditioning,Restaurant,Conference_Hall,Health_Club,Travel_Desk,Transfers,Forex,Shopping,Swimming,Banquet,Business_Center


            NA
            cdn.travelpartnerweb.com/DesiyaImages/Image/1/nxd/maw/rym/fbn/HO_TN.jpg





          N
          N
          Double Deluxe Non AC
          No Amenities
          0000018167
          0000058501

            11111111
            6rHbdJ5eYI7GHJZzEBm8BvOaNWWi+RUhLJ4p4u6ke0DPzHJ7gHRp3iyeKeLupHtAhduj3Vq+cinEOsNqkniCrj61Dp4lgPVpxhyWcxAZvAY6eaST9cxEwO77vKeHzGt7xDrDapJ4gq4OONbvuHIwepH1wYi4aVVmDxAoeeQIBeo7G/tKB6tJOYDfWwbV0F7ASAS/psz+s/vtFOZDhaz6EtGf96t/LsuWxw1Qqnbhmf3XYWyQ7VUjC8Q6w2qSeIKuoKFs0O+FVtNhRIfAcxLjf86bGU9wLBRNvD/Qlqcc//JzmIzIGoODhM1oJoq2rZMN1gD5nlU38lH0iT7gaoTgQlkLlahFGUKDXPHozEiWFpzUKxI3Gs/Qlb/GgoQwMdTKxDrDapJ4gq7T1On3xumaPlSUX+m2OTA/Sab7vcJpbRqwnS5tXPee0xRdnqSKMS+eDml0U5ncn3eFGMF7Jssn/w==
            0
            966
            44
            0.0
            0



          N
          N
          Double Deluxe AC
          No Amenities
          0000018168
          0000058502

            11111111
            sSCoszzZkH86eaST9cxEwDETzbfNeAOGmk9s1Uz6PbZGv/SG567OsZpPbNVM+j22DfbGKTDMXKFkOaDlTL6ZjC9zLGtHv0ypOnmkk/XMRMAPn02YIdZ7qUC2Sm/k4OAAweOUbgjswoF0RTNIMdh6kznLtLUAmNXdxBAFTfOqI33OVMB55THv90eKTmvZ2ac1r6XOD4IuEJXSNJKs059Edkq65LMH1OLRxhyWcxAZvAZDK+imLEcGecHjlG4I7MKBOhnNsQ2MxYZ+oLyPTZ3RMaAnkAotaRPKKfHYXniQp/S8zzpKPZaLArk7+CKaeLo9hOB8fqTxssT128imfeXuC/OgEXYIgsG2UHFvTjsO+sCf5HK8TIYqr+4vK3ryvrJwFluz6IhIkl4/hAHmlwnis6hroDhh/C42mx8+gs3lzQiWJgzCcdsB9fCEqLc7/4v1LJ4p4u6ke0CUdoTzsl6ZtBfc5EobFJGF
            0
            1318
            60
            0.0
            0






        00004788
        U.G.ROYAL
        Strategically located near to the railway station by 2kms, this smoke-free property is designed with 3floors with an elevator, and maintained with 24 rooms to reside in. The property is also maintained with a garden space and a travel counter for all travel assistance. A vegetarian fare can be savoured in the nearby Sukh Sagar Restaurant and non-vegetarian fare can be relished in any of the neighboring dining outlets, namely New Grand and Hyderabad.

        0
        2
        650
        062
        arzooB


# 42, Cottonpet Main Road

          NA

          Strategically located near to the railway station by 2kms, this smoke-free property is designed with 3floors with an elevator, and maintained with 24 rooms to reside in. The property is also maintained with a garden space and a travel counter for all travel assistance. A vegetarian fare can be savoured in the nearby Sukh Sagar Restaurant and non-vegetarian fare can be relished in any of the neighboring dining outlets, namely New Grand and Hyderabad.
          NA
          NA
          NA
          NA


          00:00
          12:00


          All
          NA
          NA

        Air_Conditioning,Restaurant,Conference_Hall,Health_Club,Travel_Desk,Transfers,Forex,Shopping,Swimming,Banquet,Business_Center


            NA
            cdn.travelpartnerweb.com/DesiyaImages/Image/1/nxd/maw/syf/lbv/HO_TN.jpg





          N
          N
          Double Deluxe Non AC
          No Amenities
          0000017219
          0000054610

            11111111
            oHS5Xd5Exyg6eaST9cxEwGZSjnNN3mhmmk9s1Uz6PbaNc1sEsAf/6JpPbNVM+j22if6NKX9Uk13Dy1lDA4noii9zLGtHv0ypOnmkk/XMRMAPn02YIdZ7qUC2Sm/k4OAAweOUbgjswoF0RTNIMdh6kznLtLUAmNXdU8J0wP+0TP07G/tKB6tJOYDfWwbV0F7ASAS/psz+s/vtFOZDhaz6EtGf96t/LsuWxw1Qqnbhmf3XYWyQ7VUjC8Q6w2qSeIKuoKFs0O+FVtN4j8rH+f6mNO5qfq4xpPlORexVeZq9N0yqKIuRorLprNQrEjcaz9CVv8aChDAx1MrEOsNqkniCrtPU6ffG6Zo+VJRf6bY5MD9Jpvu9wmltGrCdLm1c957TFF2epIoxL54OaXRTmdyfd0BBbtk2xLpA
            0
            1142
            52
            0.0
            0



          N
          N
          Deluxe Double AC
          No Amenities
          0000017221
          0000054612

            11111111
            TxbgXP3Nk6o6eaST9cxEwO0QCFlSnc8Cmk9s1Uz6PbaNc1sEsAf/6JpPbNVM+j22fMzm237c+vR3p+iuYvo+Ai9zLGtHv0ypOnmkk/XMRMAPn02YIdZ7qUC2Sm/k4OAAweOUbgjswoF0RTNIMdh6kznLtLUAmNXdU8J0wP+0TP07G/tKB6tJOYDfWwbV0F7ASAS/psz+s/vtFOZDhaz6EtGf96t/LsuWxw1Qqnbhmf3XYWyQ7VUjC8Q6w2qSeIKuoKFs0O+FVtN4j8rH+f6mNO5qfq4xpPlORexVeZq9N0yqKIuRorLprNQrEjcaz9CVv8aChDAx1MrEOsNqkniCrtPU6ffG6Zo+VJRf6bY5MD9Jpvu9wmltGrCdLm1c957TFF2epIoxL54OaXRTmdyfd4cJw1cUhwyo
            0
            1580
            72
            0.0
            0






        00004786
        U.G.GRAND
        A large photo frame of Lord Venkatesh at the lobby welcomes guests to a comfortable stay in this four floors hotel located in the NP Lane. There are 16 rooms facilitated with 24hours room service. A vegetarian fare can be relished at the Krishna Sagar Delhi Restaurant, which is open for service from 6a.m. to 10a.m., and non-vegetarian fare can be savoured in the Hyderabad Biryani Restaurant, which can be visited between 10a.m. to 11p.m. There is free valet parking facility also available in this hotel.

        0
        2
        650
        108
        arzooB


NO.10,N.P. LANE,COTTON PET BEHIND SHANTALA SILKS
```

So here i want to arrange that response in a designed format. How can i do that. Please give me your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance,
Sree ram

Comment: The soap service should return the results in valid xml or json or some other standardised format which you can then easily parse or xslt etc to display.  If its not returning in a valid already recognised format then the service provider should provide you a document explaining the format, separators etc.  If not you need to get onto them and abuse them.  Have you tried echoing out the returned text into a textarea see what its returning?  Or is it returning perhaps a direct soap object so you'd do something like `$soaprequest->destination;`

Comment: hi dave thanks for you response..

I have list of variables and i know i want to echo them but i dnt have an idea that where to echo them. for example i have written xml request code in x.php and i am executing it and then i am getting th e above response. Now my doubt is where to write the echo code..?? I am doing this for the first time...So please tell me clearly... thanks in advance..

Comment: can you post up your code so we can see how you're requesting the details from servervice. Also if you have the docs for the returned variables that'd be useful too

Comment: I have edited my question please go through that..

Comment: `__Call` is deprecated use `__soapCall` instead to access the returned fields you do $info->FieldNameToRequest the field names returned should be specified in the documentation by the provider. (also try var_dump() rather than print_r())

Comment: Just a shot in the dark. Are you sure you're looking at the result in the source code ? And not in a browser ?

Comment: @Touki Sorry i didnt understood your question...

Comment: @Dave I have used the _soapCall and the result is same.

Comment: @Sreeram Are you looking at the result in a browser or in a text editor ?

Comment: @Touki I am seeing the result in browser.

Comment: @Sreeram Just look at the source then... (usually Ctrl+U or Right click > View Source). You should have the real XML.

Comment: @Touki Yes i can see the xml code by view source.